# How to format category IDs as a string in my db

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP/MySQL. I want to minimize the number of tables I have so I've been thinking of saving an array of IDs (from checkboxes users tick off) as a string instead of in a separate table. What do you use to format the list of IDs as a string so I can easily parse the IDs for future use in my program?

Comment: It is not good if it breaks database designing tradition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
 and [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for joining the values and separating the values respectively. You can also try [serialize()](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) for storing the values. There are a lot of examples in my given links, so they will be helpful for your desirable data format.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a good idea. I think a 1:N-Relation is the better choice. This givs a better performance and the db supports integrity checks.

So if you want to, you can build a comma-separated list and than use following where-statement:

```
where CONCAT(',', FIELDWITHIDS, ',') like '%,13,%'
```

to find datasets that reference the ID 13. Or you have to use explode() and implode() in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Either comma separated values or php serialize (http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

That being said, you lose the benefit of being able to do joins or integrity checks in your DB, so you should generally avoid it.

Comment: You're so right. I forgot about doing joins. I won't be able to do any of it if it's a string.